# Amplify plugin was not added

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I got an error connecting authentication via amplify cognito user poll to my Flutter application.
After that I decided to run the example, the error remained the same.
"Amplify plugin was not added" error.

```
const amplifyconfig = ''' {
"UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
"Version": "1.0",
"auth": {
    "plugins": {
        "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
            "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
            "Version": "0.1.0",
            "IdentityManager": {
                "Default": {}
            },
            "CredentialsProvider": {
                "CognitoIdentity": {
                    "Default": {
                        "PoolId": "us-east-2:4ffdb54c-4f58-4d03-82c8-2aeaf712a292",
                        "Region": "us-east-2"
                    }
                }
            },
            "CognitoUserPool": {
                "Default": {
                    "PoolId": "us-east-2_EQLTCx5kZ",
                    "AppClientId": "bluf9opl5vi3ojlckq9env573",
                    "Region": "us-east-2"
                }
            },
            "Auth": {
                "Default": {
                    "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH",
                    "loginMechanisms": [
                        "EMAIL"
                    ],
                    "signupAttributes": [
                        "EMAIL"
                    ],
                    "passwordProtectionSettings": {
                        "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
                        "passwordPolicyCharacters": []
                    },
                    "mfaConfiguration": "OFF",
                    "mfaTypes": [
                        "SMS"
                    ],
                    "verificationMechanisms": [
                        "EMAIL"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}''';
```

the code took from this example https://pub.dev/packages/amplify_analytics_pinpoint/example

```
Amplify plugin was not added
Error: AmplifyException$(message: Amplify plugin AmplifyAuthCognito was not added successfully., recoverySuggestion: We currently don't have a recovery suggestion for this exception., underlyingException: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method addPlugin on channel com.amazonaws.amplify/auth_cognito))
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:5061:11)
    at amplify.AmplifyClass.protected.addPlugin (http://localhost:52967/packages/amplify_flutter/amplify_hub.dart.lib.js:248:25)
    at addPlugin.throw (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:38645:38
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:38515:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:33724:33)
    at handleError (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:34281:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:34307:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:34151:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:34172:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:38778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:38784:13)
    at http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:34519:9
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method configure on channel com.amazonaws.amplify/amplify)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:5061:11)
    at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:52967/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1526:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:38640:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:38511:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:33713:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:34265:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:34303:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:34151:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:34172:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:38778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:38784:13)
    at http://localhost:52967/dart_sdk.js:34519:9
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your configuration file and full error messages as **text** rather than as screenshots?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)* may also help.

Comment: A [mcve] with which we can debug your error would maximize your chances of getting help, for why see [ask].